# Android: How to know whether a bitmap on Google Maps has been clicked?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm developing an application on Android with the use of Google Map.

[image: map]

I've successfully put multiple bitmaps on the map as shown on the figure above.
Is it possible to detect which bitmap the user has clicked on, so that the application will redirect the user to a page which contains information about the place clicked?

Comment: Yup. The bitmaps are drawn on the map. Is it possible to detect which bitmap the user has clicked on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Here you will need to put some logic to capture which bitmap Image was clicked.

One technique which works in my case is to override a method in your ItemizedOverlay class

protected boolean onTap(int index) {

// Here you get the index of which bitmap image was tapped on
// You can map this index to the related activity you need to open by mean of your logic

        OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);

        Intent intent=new Intent (context,YourActivity.class);

        context.startActivity(intent);

        return true;
    }
```